# How to tell logic low and logic high from a datasheet?

Tags: datasheet

I want to control the SHDN (shutdown) pin of a FAN5333B LED driver ([datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/FAN5333.pdf)) with a 3.3V device using PWM. I was planning to drive it with 5V on V<sub>in</sub>. I see from the datasheet that logic high turns it on and that logic low turns it off, but I can't find anything about what is considered logic high and low.

I'm very new to reading datasheets; what should I be looking for? Is it just assumed knowledge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't blame you -- it's a tricky datasheet to read. I believe this is the answer you're looking for:

[image]

Normally, you'd look for a "SHDN_B VIH/VIL" specification or similar. In this case, since that table specifies all conditions are at "VIN=3.6V", I feel comfortable taking those numbers as the threshold levels.

I see that you can PWM the SHDN# pin (common on these types of parts) to get variable brightness -- this is where IMO, it would have been nice to get a labeled 'Logic Low/Logic High' threshold in the table, with the VIH and VIL numbers.

My read is that a voltage below 0.5V, at the tested conditions is guaranteed to be read as a logic '0', and a voltage at and above 1.5V, at the tested conditions is guaranteed to be logic '1'. So, your 3.3V drive will work. If this was a device where VIH was 0.7*VDD, then you might have needed to consider a level-shifter. (This is often the difference between CMOS/TTL inputs, whether VIH is a fixed number independent of VDD, or if it's a dependent value).

Additionally, I don't see a direct path between VIN and SHDN# from the block diagram, so I don't think you have too much to worry about with 5V making it to your 3.3V device -- it can't hurt to put a 0R resistor in line so you can change to say a 100R resistor in the future if you have issues.

[This application note from TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/szza036c/szza036c.pdf) is a really good resource in general for understanding datasheets. It's focused at the conventional 74xxx logic families, but I think there's a lot to be learned from it.